# Installed Chrome 61.0.3163.100-1 via ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't launch because NSS out of date

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

After installation, launching via cli throws this error

```
[4394:4456:0926/124258.542217:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
```

Policy details -

```
apt-cache policy libnss3

libnss3:
  Installed: 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:3.21-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Source List -

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse universe restricted main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse universe restricted main
```

Comment: have you tried to update to ubuntu 16.04.3?

Comment: @S.Ith I haven't tried that although automatic updates is turned on and it is showing up-to-date. Are you sure updating the version to 16.04.3 solves this specific issue? Thanks.

Comment: No, not sure, but I always do that to eliminate possible sources of the error, and of course if you does not need to stick with version 16.04.2. If after cleaning the cache, updating and upgrading to 16.04.3, the issue persists, some people reinstalled `libnss3` and worked for them.

Comment: I had an older version of NSS in my PATH. That was causing a conflict. After removing the older NSS from PATH, Chrome works.